# What's wrong with the xwatermark package?

Tags: warnings, mactex, compilation-error, xwatermark

On a relatively old MacTeX distribution (2015), the following code was compiling fine without any issue.  But with the latest MacTeX, it doesn't compile well anymore.  I'm getting some mysterious error at compilation and I don't see where's the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}

 Blabla

\end{document}
```

In the console, I'm getting these two incomprehensible warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `atbegshi',
           but the package provides `atbegshi-ltx'.

 LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `atveryend',
           but the package provides `atveryend-ltx'.
```

So what's wrong here?  How should I use that `xwatermark` package with the latest MacTeX distribution?

**EDIT:**  It seems that this package doesn't work anymore with LaTeX.  I'll need to replace that package with something else.

Comment: Only tangentially related here... But I'd consider trying tectonic over the classic distributions these days :) https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/ (I'm only involved in the project insofar as I've submitted issues). It aims to make builds more deterministic and repeatable, decoupling them from system packages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark
`xwatermark` "is currently unmaintained and does not work with modern LaTeX releases."

You probably want to use the `watermark` package instead. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/watermark

Answer (score 3):

I've found `draftwatermark` to be a reliable alternative for `xwatermark` (using XeLaTeX).

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftwatermark